# Execution a deployment script on a remote ssh server through a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I've got a Jenkins pipeline containing stages for source loading, building and deploying on a remote machine through SSH. The problem is about the last one. I saved the script of the following template on the remote server:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash /<pathTo>/jboss-cli.sh --command="deploy /<anotherPath>/service.war --force"
```

It works fine if executed in a terminal connected to the remote server.

The best outcome I've received through Jenkins is

`/<pathTo>/jboss-cli.sh: line 87: usr/bin/java/bin/java: No such file or directory`

in Jenkins console output.

Tried switching between bash and sh, exporting path to java in the pipeline script etc.

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks!

p.s. Execution call from Jenkins looks like:

```
sh """
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $connectionName 'bash /<pathToTheScript>/<scriptName>.sh'
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line 87: **usr/bin/java/bin/java**: No such file or directory
```

As per error line it is considering path from **usr** not **/usr**. Can you check if this is what the problem is?

Sorry, I know this should be in comments section but I don't have right to add comments yet.

Comment: So the reason for that is left unknown but I fixed the issue with your help. So initially, the line 87 used a variable, initialized such as (also inside jboss-cli.sh):
JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
Consequently, $JAVA_HOME values were different (why?) through Jenkins and through a terminal on the server.
So I echo'ed the value in the terminal and hardcoded it in the jboss-cli.sh (/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java) to be like:
JAVA="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java"
Now redeploying works after a build correctly. Thank you. Still appreciate any thoughts about the reason :)